# Continuous Dependence on Initial Conditions of Solution to an ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Say $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with real, distinct eigenvalues and $\phi(t,\mathbf{x}_0)$ is the solution of the IVP
\begin{align*}
\dot{\mathbf{x}}=A\mathbf{x}\\
\mathbf{x}(0)=\mathbf{x}_0
\end{align*}

I need to prove that the solution depends continuously on the initial condition.

To show this, I know I need to prove $\lim_{\mathbf{y}_0\to\mathbf{x}_0}\phi(t,\mathbf{y}_0)=\phi(t,\mathbf{x}_0)$. I think I'd be able to show this if it were a one-dimensional problem. But being a general multidimensional problem like this makes it a bit confusing for me. Like for example, is the fact that the matrix $A$ has real, distinct eigenvalues play any role in the proof? If so, how?

How can I show that the limit is true?

Comment: $x(t)=e^{tA}x_0$.

Comment: @Artem Should the $\phi$ here always be the same as $x(t)$ as you said?

Comment: Yes, in your notation $\phi(t,x)=e^{tA}x$.